# Django: QuerySet filter doesn't work as expected

Tags: python, django

I have the following QuerySet.

```
from myapp.events.models import Event
from myapp.surveys import QuestionFocus
from django.conf import settings

event = Event.objects.get(pk=12)
survey = event.surveys.get(
    template=settings.SURVEY_POST_EVENT
).questions.filter(
    focus=QuestionFocus.RECOMMENDATION_TO_FRIENDS,
    answers__answer="9"
).prefetch_related("answers")

survey.first().answers.all()
```

Now I expect only two of the answers (9). However, somehow my filter request is completely ignored. Do you see what I am doing wrong?

```
>>> <QuerySet [Answer: 2, Answer: 9, Answer: 9, Answer: 10]>
```

Answer model:

```
class Answer(TimeStampedModel):
    question = models.ForeignKey(
        "surveys.Question", on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="answers"
    )
    response = models.ForeignKey(
        "Response", on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="answers"
    )
    answer = models.TextField(verbose_name=_("Answer"))
    choices = models.ManyToManyField(
        "surveys.AnswerOption", related_name="answers", blank=True
    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your current design, one `Question` instance can be related to many `Answer` instances. So `survey.first()` returns you the first filtered `Question`, and `.answers.all()` on that returns all the related answer instances.

Your `answers__answer="9"` filter is working perfectly; as you have such a relationship it will show only the `Question` instances that contain `answers` with having `answer` field value of `9`.

---

Perhaps you want to establish one-to-one between `Question` and `Answer` or many-to-one from `Question` to `Answer` if many questions can have one common answer.